# tensorQTL interaction issue

Tags: genomics, genetics, qtls

I hope that the question has its place on this board.

I am trying to run the mapping of cis eQTL using an interaction term with tensorQTL. I am running into the following index error when running the software:

```
>>> cis.map_nominal(genotype_df, variant_df,
...                 phenotype_df,
...                 phenotype_pos_df,
...                 prefix = prefix,
...                 covariates_df=covariates_df,
...                 interaction_df=interaction_s,
...                 maf_threshold_interaction=0.05,
...                 run_eigenmt=True,
...                 output_dir=output,
...                 write_top=True,
...                 write_stats=True)
cis-QTL mapping: nominal associations for all variant-phenotype pairs
  * 569 samples
  * 24665 phenotypes
  * 68 covariates
  * 69763935 variants
  * including 1 interaction term(s)
    * using 0.05 MAF threshold
  * cis-window: ±1,000,000
  * checking phenotypes: 24665/24665
  * Computing associations
    Mapping chromosome 1
    processing phenotype 137/24665Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/QRISdata/Q5776/software/tensorqtl/tensorqtl/core.py", line 197, in calculate_interaction_nominal
    Xinv = torch.matmul(torch.transpose(X_t, 1, 2), X_t).inverse() # ng x (1+2*ni) x (1+2*ni)
torch._C._LinAlgError: linalg.inv: (Batch element 2704): The diagonal element 3 is zero, the inversion could not be completed because the input matrix is singular.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/QRISdata/Q5776/software/tensorqtl/tensorqtl/cis.py", line 294, in map_nominal
    res = calculate_interaction_nominal(genotypes_t, phenotype_t.unsqueeze(0), interaction_t,
  File "/QRISdata/Q5776/software/tensorqtl/tensorqtl/core.py", line 200, in calculate_interaction_nominal
    i = int(re.findall('For batch (\d+)', str(e))[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, when I run the same command but only on 50 genes, the code runs properly.

```
>>> cis.map_nominal(genotype_df, variant_df,
...                 phenotype_df.iloc[1:50],
...                 phenotype_pos_df.iloc[1:50],
...                 prefix = prefix,
...                 covariates_df=covariates_df,
...                 interaction_df=interaction_s,
...                 maf_threshold_interaction=0.05,
...                 run_eigenmt=True,
...                 output_dir=output,
...                 write_top=True,
...                 write_stats=True)
cis-QTL mapping: nominal associations for all variant-phenotype pairs
  * 569 samples
  * 49 phenotypes
  * 68 covariates
  * 69763935 variants
  * including 1 interaction term(s)
    * using 0.05 MAF threshold
  * cis-window: ±1,000,000
  * checking phenotypes: 49/49
  * Computing associations
    Mapping chromosome 1
    processing phenotype 49/49
    time elapsed: 0.44 min
    * writing output
done.
```

The interaction factor is a categorical variable (0/1), I am not sure why the issue is being raised and how to fix

I would appreciate any help/direction to go forward.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a solution for anyone interested. The issue stems from a dosage error, some variant contains only heterozygous individuals and no homozygous ones needed for QTL calculation.

I used plink2 to calculate genotypes for all variant using the following command:

```
plink2  --pfile PATH \
     --geno-counts  \
     --out OUT
```

I then removed variant that contains less than 10 Homozygous invidivuals (HOM_REF_CT < 10) using plink then was able to run tensorQTL interaction mode.

Hope it helps.